# Handling multiple users editing the same information angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, time

hey how to handle multiple users editing same information? like by editing a patient using two browsers/users. Two browsers should start the edit process. One changes and saves, and the other browser changes to different values and attempt to save (but it should be rejected) 
how can i achieve that?

**my html file file**

```
<ng-template #content>
<form
role="form"
#createPatientForm="ngForm"
(ngSubmit)="onLogin(createPatientForm.value)"
novalidate>
<div class="modal-body" *ngIf="!editMode || !confirm">
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="fName" class="col-8">
          <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
          <input
            #fName="ngModel"
            type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="patient.FirstName"
            name="firstName"
            class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
            [ngClass]="{ invalid: !fName.valid && fName.touched }"
            id="firstName"
            autocomplete="off"
            minlength="2"
            maxlength="20"
            required
          />
        </div>

      <div *ngIf="!fName.valid && fName.touched" class="error">
        <div *ngIf="fName.errors.required">First Name is required.  </div>
        <div *ngIf="fName.errors.minlength">Minimum of 2 characters.</div>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="!mName.valid && mName.touched" class="error">
        <div *ngIf="mName.errors.pattern">
          Numbers not allowed for initials.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="mName.errors.minlength">Minimum of 2 characters.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name*</label>
      <input
        #lName="ngModel"
        type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="patient.LastName"
        name="lastName"
        class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
        [ngClass]="{ invalid: !lName.valid && lName.touched }"
        id="lastName"
        autocomplete="off"
        minlength="2"
        maxlength="50"
        inputName
        required
      />

      <div *ngIf="!lName.valid && lName.touched" class="error">
        <div *ngIf="lName.errors.required">Last Name is required.</div>
        <div *ngIf="lName.errors.minlength">Minimum of 2 characters.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="Gender">Gender*</label>
          <select
            #gender="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="patient.Gender"
            [class.text-dimmed]="!patient.Gender"
            name="gender"
            id="Gender"
            class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
            [ngClass]="{ invalid: gender.value === null && gender.touched }"
            required
          >
            <option [ngValue]="null">Select</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
          <div *ngIf="gender.value === null && gender.touched">
            <div class="error">Gender required.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="patientEmail">Email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        #email="ngModel"
        [(ngModel)]="patient.Email"
        name="patientEmail"
        class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
        [ngClass]="{ invalid: !email.valid && email.touched }"
        id="patientEmail"
        minlength="5"
        maxlength="100"
        pattern="^(?!.*(?:''|\.\.))[\w-\.\']{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,3}$"
      />
      <div class="error" *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched">
        <div *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">
          Please enter a valid email address.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="email.errors.minlength">
          minimum of 5 characters required.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hint-section">
      <p class="address-header text-center">
        * Required
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <span (click)="cancel()" class="clickable">CANCEL</span>
  <button
    [disabled]="
      checkFormValidity(createPatientForm) || !createPatientForm.form.valid
    "
    type="button"
    class="btn square-btn"
    (click)="editMode && confirm ? setConfirm() : createUpdatePatient()"
  >
    {{ editMode && confirm ? "YES" : "NEXT" }}
  </button>
</div>
```

**here is my Ts file**

```
 createUpdatePatient() {
this.duplicateFinderService.confirmDuplicatePatient(
  this.dateOfBirth,
  this.patient,
  this.mode,
  this.patientId
);
this.router.navigate(["../additional-details"], {
  relativeTo: this.route
  });
}
```

**additional detail ts file**

```
  update() {
this.requestPending = true;
this.patientService.updatePatientProfile(this.patient).subscribe(
  () => {
    this.store.dispatch(
      new SetPatientAction(this.patient, this.utilService)
    );
    this.requestPending = false;
    if (this.isAdminEdit) {
      this.router.navigate(["../billing"], { relativeTo: this.route });
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(["../"], { relativeTo: this.route });
    }
  },
  error => {
    this.requestPending = false;
     }
   );
 }
```

**billing detail**

```
  update() {
this.requestPending = true;
this.patientService.updatePatientBilling(this.patient).subscribe(() => {
  this.requestPending = false;
  this.store.dispatch(new SetPatientAction(this.patient, this.utilService));
  this.cancel();
  });
}
```

can i achieve that in frontend? thanks

Comment: I suggest you look into websockets.

Comment: would you kindly provide me more details? @Carsten

Comment: Google usually knows more than I do. https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1

Comment: You would need some kind of logic in the server side to handle such scenarios.You can probably make use of webrtc to acheive it purely on  frontend. But it would be an overkill for this functionality.

Comment: You need to involve server side too , to achieve this. you can use Websocket or signalR if you are from .net background

Answer (score 0):

Based on userId you can achieve it.Track each user Id and implement changes according to that

Comment: is there any help i can get to achieve that? @ankit mishra

Comment: { path: 'user', component: UserSaveUpdateComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'user/:id', component: UserSaveUpdateComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService] },

Comment: use this in routing component and while submitting get the id in ts file of your respective component and then using service class hit controller at backend and save or update queries based on particular id

Comment: so it means backend will be involved? @ankit mishra

Comment: @usman saleem: yes because the input of different users you should save somewhere right?

Comment: yeah right thanks i will try to use it thanks :) @ankit mishra